# (Bootstrap) form's multiselect returning "Array" as result

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm new to creating contact forms on websites, where the contact form sends the messages to my email.

- I am using Bootstrap, and this mulitselect plugin: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect
- My form is based on this Bootstrap template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/
- I'm using the Bootstrap form validation plugin.

**My problem is**, when items are selected from the dropdown multiselect on the contact form, and once the form is submitted, the email comes through with "Array" as value for the muliselect option. I have checked on the contact form, that the multiselect array did return the correct selected values, so the array was not empty, but once it goes to the js and php files it seemed the data were lost, or I'm declaring something wrongly?

Below are the codes where I've added in parts to the templates.
The multiselect code on my contact form file:

```
<div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                      <label>Solid Surfaces</label>
                      <select id="solidSurfacesID" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="Acrylico">Acrylico</option>
                        <option value="ANGES">AGNES</option>
                        <option value="AVONITE">AVONITE</option>
                        <option value="Ante">Ante (Avonite)</option>
                        <option value="AULLAND">AULLAND</option>
                        <option value="Basix">Basix</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And this is the script for it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#solidSurfacesID').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

In the separate contact_me.js:

```
// get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var solidSurfacesID = $("#solidSurfacesID").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    solidSurfacesID: solidSurfacesID,
                    message: message
                },
```

And in the contact_me.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$solidSurfacesID = $_POST['solidSurfacesID'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: need to implode the array or loop over it depending on how you want to format in email

Comment: Ah I see! Works now! Thank you so much :)